# Storing userID in sessions

Tags: php, security, session

When I read about sessions, I mostly find the userID is stored in the session. I have created a login page that stores the username and status. Assume the username is unique. So when the user logs in, I can output:

Hi, username.

If I have to change something in the database, I can just do:

```
statement where username= username in the session
```

so why do we have to store the userID in the session?

Comment: can you post some actual code? and what exactly is your situation?
Storing the userID in the session helps to have a better perfomance and you can store the name which you got from the database as well in the session. How do you handle sessions?

Comment: @JRsz "Storing the userID in the session helps to have a better performance" - exactly why I ask. I'm not using the userID, I'm using the username to do something in the database. Assuming the username is unique. Why should we use userID rather than username?

Comment: Because there can be two people who have the same name. Having a userID for each user can give you an ifentifier of the user even if there are two with the same name, which is not uncommen. Since not everyone can remember their id use something other uniquely to identify them, like a self picked username or an email adress. Get information out of the database and associate a user with a unique id, this has proven to be quiet effective in most scenarios

Comment: It depends on how you builded your own system. Most developers prefer `user_id's` because mostly the ID is the primary key in databases and makes queries a lot easier for example: `UPDATE users SET username='donut' WHERE user_id='1'`. The ID from the user is static and cannot be edited by the user himself.

Answer (score 0):

Look we store some needed information of `logged in` `user` in `session` which we require in our `project`. This reduce the time of `execution` `query` each time

Suppose you need `logged in` user id some where then you have to execute a `query` using `username` conditionally but if you have stored `userid` in `session` then you can easily get it. 
This is also helpful in projects where we maintain logs of `logged in` user or if a user changed some `access` of other and you have to store id of user which changed that then you can use that.

The need differs from `project` to `project`